Power Automate - How to remove Microsoft 365 Group from Folder permissions in SharePoint
I have a requirement to remove all permissions from a new doc set each time one is created, then have my flow grant specific permissions from there.  I have several Send an HTTP Request to SharePoint actions that successfully break inheritance, gather the SP users, then remove them.  This works perfectly, but ONLY for Sharepoint groups.  When I look at the "Manage Access" for the doc sets, there is still a Microsoft 365 Group (Owners) which still has access.  How could I also remove that group from Folder permissions?  I see there's a Send an HTTP Request V2 action - would I use that?  I don't want to mess with the group on a level higher than just removing them from the Folders in this Library.  How could I go about doing this?
Thank you!

Unfortunately, Microsoft 365 group's permissions to a SharePoint site created by  using Team Site template with default settings can't be removed. In other words, these SharePoint sites cant' be disconnected from Microsoft 365 groups.
However, Site Collections can be created with Team Template without Microsoft 365 group. Please see this article

Also, it is not possible to delete the site permanently without deleting the Microsoft 365 group, and deleting the group will delete the site itself.
See this MS Article
Hope this helps!
